# decorators during validation still work if the field is nullable

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

I use [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) .
But after reading the documentation of this package and `graphql` in general, I still did not find how to solve this problem

Have this mutation:

```
@Mutation(() => UserEntity)
  async updateUserById(
    @Args('id') id: string,
    @Args('inputs') inputs: UpdateUserDto
  )
    : Promise<UserEntity> {
    return await this.userService.updateUserById(id, inputs)
  }
```

and my Dto looks like:

```
@InputType()
export class UpdateUserDto {

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @IsString()
  fullName?: string;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @IsEmail()
  @IsString()
  email?: string;

  @Field({nullable: true, description: 'Password must be longer than or equal to 5 characters'})
  @MinLength(5)
  @IsString()
  password?: string;

  @Field({nullable: true})
  @IsString()
  phoneNumber?: string
}
```

And when i want update one field:

```
mutation{
  updateUserById(id:"847025d8-0e6f-4456-88f7-710b104db6ca", 
    inputs:{
    fullName:"New name"
  })
  {
    fullName
  }
}
```

Still getting errors from working decorators even if the field is nullable:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": {
        "statusCode": 400,
        "error": "Bad Request",
        "message": [
          {
            "target": {
              "fullName": "New name"
            },
            "constraints": {
              "isString": "email must be a string",
              "isEmail": "email must be an email"
            }
          },
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

resolved by adding `@IsOptional()` decorator